# increment label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a button that adds a new row to the view with the following code. Is there a way to increment the label? What I would like is to say "Name 1:" "Name 2:" for every row.

```
string s = "<table>\r\n";    
s += "  <tr>\r\n";
s += "    <td>\r\n";
s += "      <label>Name: </label>";
s += "      <input></input>";
s += "    </td>\r\n";
s += "    <td>\r\n"
s += "</table>\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the index of that previous row into whatever calls this code.  Add 1.